# Windows XP network issue - Looking for wrong Workgroup

Tags: networking, windows-xp

Say my workgroup name is "MyGroup".  Every time I pull up Windows Explorer, go to My Network Places and then Computers Near Me, I keep getting a message that says, "MyGroup2 is not accessible..."  I then go to Control Panel and System, and it clearly says my workgroup is called "MyGroup".  So why on earth is it looking for MyGroup2, and how do I convince it that it should be looking for MyGroup??  I should note that when I installed Windows I did have it in the MyGroup2 workgroup, then discovered that it should have been called MyGroup.  However, after I changed it back I'd expect it to look for MyGroup but for some reason MyGroup2 is stuck in it's brain.

This is a new build, I recently reformatted the HD on this machine.  Also, it **can** connect to my wireless network and get online.  Also, the other computers on MyGroup can see the new computer, making matters even weirder...

Comment: Might be a silly question but did you restart your computer after you changed your Workgroup?

Comment: Yes.  About 10 times.  :o)  I'm wondering if I need to uninstall TCP/IP and reinstall it or something?  It's just weird that it still looking for the old workgroup.

Comment: 2 different locations on the web said that the phantom workgroup will eventually disappear on its own after time, A oddity of the Network Browser service. I think it is also based on it no longer being used too?  So if it doesnt go away in a few days, maybe you could change the others so that it is no longer attempted to be used? I can not believe that nobody just backed up the registry searched for it and deleted it there?

Comment: I did search through the registry and deleted any 2's that followed my workgroup name.  I further deduced that if I right click on "Computers Near Me" and checked the Properties, the Target is still listed as MyGroup2.  I changed it to something completely different ("YOMOMMA" actually...) and rebooted, and it still thinks the target is MyGroup2.  I'm stumped.